# Converting a large decimal with percentage sign (%) to a smaller decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have the following data that I need to convert to a simple decimal.  Currently, it is in varchar format. The data is in a column called Commission%

| Commission% (currently Varchar) | Commission% V2 (needs to be decimal) |
| --- | --- |
| 87.00000% | .87 |
| 95.00000% | .95 |

I have tried the following:

```
CAST(CAST(CONVERT(FLOAT,REPLACE([Commission %], ''%'', '''')) / 100 AS DECIMAL(10,6)) as DECIMAL(10,6))
```

BUT I get the following error message **Error converting data type varchar to numeric**.  I was able to use something similar the other day but there were fewer trailing zero's at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost certainly due to bad data which is what you should expect when you store numbers as strings. Here is how you identify them:

```
SELECT [KeyColumn], [Commission%] 
  FROM dbo.BadColumnNamesWow
  WHERE [Commission%] IS NOT NULL
    AND TRY_CONVERT(decimal(20,10), REPLACE([Commission%], '%', '')) IS NULL;
```

Since you now say there are other patterns, it might make sense to just do this to identify all of the bad data:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.BadColumnNamesWow
  WHERE [Commission%] IS NOT NULL
    AND PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', [Commission%]) > 0;
```

Then clean it up. This should be a lesson in why you never store numeric values in string columns.

Comment: I definitely have bad data in my column,  In addition to 87.00000% there is 92.0000$ and blanks.  I have some additional replace statements and IIF statements to combat this but I am still getting an error converting data.  There is probably some additional bad data I am missing.

Comment: If you know you have so much bad data that you can't even enumerate all of them in a question, you should focus on fixing it before you do anything like try to convert it all to a numeric type.

Comment: (And if you have blanks and other garbage _on top of_ bad characters appended to valid values, how do you want to handle that? Reject the row, change it to 0%, change it to 100%, something else?)

Comment: I had so much bad data it actually wasn't even that column but a different one (though this column was causing errors too but with enough IIF statements and replace statements anything is possible I guess lol).  Unfortunately, the data is not something I can really change because it is how our client sends it to us.  I am just trying my best to interpret for our site/database.

Sorry, I am pretty new at all this so I do appreciate your help! I thought FLOAT wasn't working because of all the additionals 0's but it was just another column :/